# Getting wrong multiplication result in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm working in a C code for calculating pi with the precision of 80 decimals, using Archimedes method. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rJdkhlWZVQ&t=736s) may elucidate about the method.

I'm basically calculating Pi by starting with a regular hexagon with diameter 2, and sides measuring 1 and doing *Pi = Perimeter/Diameter*, and doubling the number of sizes so I can get a polygon closer to a circle each time my program calculates it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    long double pi, circunferencia, s, s1, a, b, diametro;
    int lado = 6;

    s=1;
    diametro = 2;

    while (lado<=(6*pow(2,27))){

        printf("numero de lados =%d\n", lado);

        a= sqrt(1-(s/2)*(s/2));
      //  printf("a= %.80Lf\n", a);
        b= 1 - a;
      //  printf("b= %.80Lf\n", b);
        s1= sqrt ((b*b)+((s/2)*(s/2)));
      //  printf("c= %.80Lf\n", s1);


        lado = lado*2;
        s = s1;
        circunferencia = lado * s1;
        pi = circunferencia/diametro;
        printf("\npi= %.80Lf\n\n\n", pi);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

With 2<sup>27</sup>, I got up to about 15 decimals of precision, and *lado* = 805306368. If I do 2<sup>28</sup> or higher, the multiplication goes wrong from this part and I start to get negative numbers.  Everything gets messed up and *lado*, suddenly is set to 0 and it turns into a infinite loop.

I'm a beginner in C and programming in general, if you guys could recommend me some reading on the subject, in order to understand how exactly this works and why am I getting this bug, it would be awesome.

I'm using Code::Blocks version 17.12, GNU GCC Compiler (I have "*Have gcc follow the 2011 ISO C language standard [-std=c11]*" option enabled, because I couldn't use `"%Lf"` to refer to a `long double` variable) and a Windows 10 x64 Operational System.

Comment: Max value for a signed 32-bit int is 2^31-1.

Comment: Are you really trying to compare an `int` value to something that's likely larger than 2 gig?

Comment: And note, that your `lado` is starting from `6`, so you basically iterating up to `6*(2^27)`. Which is the same as `3*2^(28)` and in the last iteration you will perform additional multiplication.

Comment: `long double` does not have that kind of precision. At most you're going to get ~20 places. Anything more precise requires specialized numerical libraries. [Welcome to floating point math](https://floating-point-gui.de).

Comment: @tadman The problem the OP is observing is not about FP math, but a simple integer overflow.

Comment: Yes, but the floating point precision is likely exhausted at or before `pow (2, 24)`.

Comment: Why use `double sqrt(double)` with `long double s` instead of `long double sqrtl(long double x)`?

Comment: I declared lado as a long double and it didn't bug, but after lado =50331648 it gave me the same result for pi, i believe due to what @tadman said.
So even if i can do up to 2^500 i can't still have better precision than 3.14159265358979 with this code.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @chux As I mentioned, I'm learning C now and I'm just messing around blindly. I'm not even sure if I did understood what you meant.

Comment: There's limits on what floating point values can express, and often these limits are a lot tighter than you think. For arbitrary precision you should look at a library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org). For example: [Calculate pi to an unlimited number of positions](https://gmplib.org/pi-with-gmp.html).

Comment: @tadman thanks, I'll read about it.

Answer (score 4):

> If i do 2^28 or higher, the multiplication goes wrong from this part,

`lado<=(6*pow(2,27))` is OK, yet `lado = lado*2;` begins to overflow `int` math about then.

Once `lado > INT_MAX/2` (likely 1,073,741,823), `int` overflow occurs with `lado*2` and anything may happen.  In OP's case, `lado` eventually become 0.

Code could use `long long`

```
// int lado = 6;
long long lado = 6;
...
  // printf("numero de lados =%d\n", lado);
  printf("numero de lados =%lld\n", lado);
```

That will patch the immediate loop concern for about another 20 or 
so loops.

---

I have my doubts that code will achieve "calculating pi with the precision of 80 decimals" with `long double` (maybe 17 - 34 decimal digits precision).

---

OP reported "my teacher said i could storage up to 80 digits with long double" certainty meant a `long double` of 80 **bits** [x86 extended precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) or about 20 *decimal* digits of precision.

I suggest using `long double` functions instead of `double` ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  long double pi, circunferencia, s, s1, a, b, diametro;
  long long lado = 6;

  s = 1;
  diametro = 2;

  while (lado <= (6 * pow(2, 27))) {
    printf("numero de lados =%lld\t", lado);

    // a = sqrt(1 - (s / 2) * (s / 2));
    a = sqrtl(1 - (s / 2) * (s / 2));
    b = 1 - a;
    // s1 = sqrt((b * b) + ((s / 2) * (s / 2)));
    s1 = hypotl(b, s / 2);

    lado = lado * 2;
    s = s1;
    circunferencia = lado * s1;
    pi = circunferencia / diametro;
    printf("pi= %.40Lf\n", pi);
  }
  printf("best                      \tpi= %.40Lf\n", acosl(-1.0));
  return 0;
}
```

Sample Output

```
numero de lados =6  pi= 3.1058285412302491482368360653509853364085
numero de lados =12 pi= 3.1326286132812381970275117382129792531487
numero de lados =24 pi= 3.1393502030468672071242958176995330177306
....
numero de lados =201326592  pi= 3.1415926535897932057699033503439522974077
numero de lados =402653184  pi= 3.1415926535897932296223511450250498455716
numero de lados =805306368  pi= 3.1415926535897932356938833109438746760134
best                        pi= 3.1415926535897932385128089594061862044327
// in my case good to about     1 23456789012345678 (18 digits)
```